# How to find the privileges granted to a user in AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using a Redshift cluster.

Version:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.735
```

I just need to drop a user but it gives the following error message:

```
redshiftpocdb=# drop user test_55;
ERROR:  user "test_55" cannot be dropped because the user has a privilege on some object
```

Here is the output of the `\dp` command:

```
redshiftpocdb=# \dp
              Access privileges
 schema |  name   | type  | access privileges
--------+---------+-------+-------------------
 public | company | table |
 public | test2   | table |
 public | test22  | table |
 public | test222 | table |
 public | v_date  | table |
(5 rows)
```

In a Postgresql environment, we have the command `DROP OWNED BY` but it does not work in Redshift.

How can I find out what privileges were granted to the `TEST_55` user? Is there any system view we can query ( for e..g in Oracle, we have DBA_ROLE_PRIVS, DBA_TAB_PRIVS...DBA_SYS_PRIVS .etc )?

Comment: There are various role/grants related views in `information_schema`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/information-schema.html

Answer (score 14):

To be able to drop a user, you have to (at least)

- if they own any objects, change the owner to a different user
- remove grants from any objects
- remove them from groups
- remove grants from schemas

You can use this to find any tables they own (then run "alter table owner to "):

```
select * from pg_tables where tableowner = 'test_55'
```

You can use this to build the script to revoke any grants:

```
select relacl , 
'revoke ' || substring(
            case when charindex('r',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',select ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('w',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',update ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('a',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',insert ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('d',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',delete ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('R',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',rule ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('x',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',references ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('t',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',trigger ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('X',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',execute ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('U',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',usage ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('C',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',create ' else '' end 
          ||case when charindex('T',split_part(split_part(array_to_string(relacl, '|'),pu.usename,2 ) ,'/',1)) > 0 then ',temporary ' else '' end 
       , 2,10000)
|| ' on '||namespace||'.'||item ||' from "'||pu.usename||'";' as grantsql
from 
(SELECT 
 use.usename as subject, 
 nsp.nspname as namespace, 
 c.relname as item, 
 c.relkind as type, 
 use2.usename as owner, 
 c.relacl 
 FROM 
 pg_user use 
 cross join pg_class c 
 left join pg_namespace nsp on (c.relnamespace = nsp.oid) 
 left join pg_user use2 on (c.relowner = use2.usesysid)
 WHERE 
 c.relowner = use.usesysid  
 and  nsp.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast', 'information_schema')
 ORDER BY   subject,   namespace,   item 
) join pg_user pu on array_to_string(relacl, '|') like '%'||pu.usename||'%' 
where relacl is not null
 and pu.usename='test_55'
```

You can use a variation of this query to see if a user belongs to any groups (then use "alter group drop user "):

```
select usesysid, usename, nvl(groname,'default') from pg_user u 
left join pg_group g on ','||array_to_string(grolist,',')||','
  like '%,'||cast(usesysid as varchar(10))||',%' 
where usename='test_55' order by 2,1;
```

You can use this query to see if they have any schema grants:

```
select * from pg_namespace where nspowner > 1 and array_to_string(nspacl,',') like '%test_55%';
```

Comment: Hi Mike, when i ran the above script to revoke any grant, i am getting below messsage: ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type aclitem[]
HINT:  Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query. How to suppress this ? could you please provide me modified query ? I am using amazon redshift ( db ver: 8.0.2 ) Thank you

Comment: My apologies.  The last line "order by 1" should be removed.  I forgot I had added relacl to the selected fields in order to show the raw privileges.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I've been fighting for over an hour to drop a user from Redshift and it turns out there were some schemas they owned that I didn't even know existed! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, to get all users' privilege organized together:

```
WITH 
usrs as (SELECT * FROM pg_user),
objs as (
  SELECT 
    schemaname, 't' AS obj_type,
    tablename AS objectname,
    schemaname + '.' + tablename AS fullobj
  FROM pg_tables
  WHERE schemaname not in ('pg_internal')
  UNION
  SELECT 
    schemaname, 'v' AS obj_type, 
    viewname AS objectname, 
    schemaname + '.' + viewname AS fullobj 
  FROM pg_views
  WHERE schemaname NOT IN ('pg_internal')
),
query as (
  SELECT 
    schemaname,
    objectname,
    usename,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'select') AS sel,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'insert') AS ins,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'update') AS upd,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'delete') AS del,
    HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usrs.usename, fullobj, 'references') AS ref
  FROM objs, usrs
  ORDER BY fullobj
)
SELECT * FROM query
WHERE (
  sel = TRUE 
  OR ins = TRUE 
  OR upd = TRUE 
  OR del = TRUE 
  OR ref = TRUE
) AND schemaname='[optional schemaname]'
  AND usename = '[optional username]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use || to concatenate strings, and a little difference as I have case-sensitive object names
'"' || schemaname || '"."' || tablename || '"' AS fullobj
'"' || schemaname || '"."' || viewname || '"' AS fullobj

instead of
schemaname + '.' + tablename  AS fullobj
schemaname + '.' + viewname  AS fullobj